# Assembly 6800 Looping? Testing specific bits in a word

Tags: assembly, motorola

Trying to help a friend out with a friend out with some assembly code, but I've run into a small problem.

I'm trying to work out how I would loop through a 8 bit binary word and check the value of specific bits. I need to check bits 1, 3, 5 & 7 to see if they are 1.

i.e.

```
int count = 1; 
int bitAdd = 0;
foreach (var bit in word) {
    if ((count = 1 && bit = 1) || (count = 3 && bit = 1) || (count = 5 && bit = 1) || (count = 7 && bit = 1)) {
      bitAdd += 1;
    }
    count += 1;
}
```

Help is much appreciated.

//Edit 
Sorry, pusdo code was a bit ambiguous. Tried to make it a little more succinct.

Comment: You've titled this 6800, but tagged it 68000, which is it?

Comment: This is not 6800 specific, but do you know `binary and`?

(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_and)

If you make a binary and with e.g. `00010000` the result will just contain zeroes if the fifth bit was zero and a non-zero value if the fifth bit was 1. (`01101010 && 00010000 = 00000000`, `01110110 && 00010000 = 00010000`).

Comment: @Neil, not a lot so far. I'm really just looking for a starting point. The documentation that this particular class was given isn't exactly easy to navigate. 

@Jimmeh, it's 6800, I don't have sufficient reputation to create a new tag. 

@phimuemue, yes I know binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the BTST instruction will be of use to you here.

http://68k.hax.com/BTST

For example:

```
btst #5, d0
```

Will check if bit 5 in the value in d0 is set.

(This will work for the 68000, I'm not too sure about the 6800, googling tells me that BITA or BITB instructions might be of use: http://www.textfiles.com/programming/CARDS/6800 )